# When I export object as .fbx, it creates some artifacts and that's why I can't bake normal and other maps and texture it in any other software

Tags: rendering, export, artifacts

[image: Blender]

This is how the object is looking in Blender
[image: In any other software]

And this is how the object is looking in any other software as Unity or Marmoset Toolbag.

I don't know what to do about it.
This is my [.blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/b/jj7XdPnZ/)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: show us you blend file

Comment: @Chris I added the blend file for you :D

Comment: thank you. unfortunately i cannot help you because i don't know the reason for that. Your model looks good to me. The only "idea" i had is to try to subdivide your 2 front faces because they are pretty big and ngons....maybe that helps

Comment: Okay, I  will try, thank you